Is there a way to get final Docker file created by devcontainer.json?
I prepared a devcontainer.json with a few features and command added to it. A simplified version looks like this:
{
    "name": "Python 3",
    "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/python:1-3.12-bullseye",
    "features": {
        "azure-cli": "latest"
    },
    "postCreateCommand": "pip3 install --user -r /workspaces/Workflows/requirements.txt"
}


Is there a way to get final Docker file created by devcontainer.json?
The Dockerfile source code helps me understand how dev containers work under the hood, and I can re-use it for my other projects.
